# Is there imresize analog that can work with more than 8 bit colors in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, image-resizing

I want to resize image that's represented by `uint16` values in each color channel. If I use `imresize` it converts data to `uint8` values. How can I preserve `uint16` and resize image?

Also I would like to use `interp='lanczos'` resizing method - to not just shrink data but preserve details. Is there `imresize` analog that can work with more than 8 bit colors in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OpenCV `resize` function: [OpenCV Documenation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)) instead of SkiPy `imresize`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: promote to `int32`, and set the mode argument to tell PIL to respect it:

```
scipy.misc.imresize(
    my_data.astype(np.int32),
    size=..., interp=..., mode='I'
).astype(np.uint16)
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. It converts 'I' format to 8 bit before resize.

Comment: What do you mean? The type of the result is `np.int32`, not `np.uint8`

Comment: The type could be `np.int32`, but the values are converted to `np.uint8` (0..255).

Comment: That feels like a bug in at least one of pillow or scipy